# underline not appear on anchor hover even though it is in CSS

Tags: css

For some reason when I hover over the anchors in #navigationText, only the cursor changed to pointer, but the text-decoration:underline does not take effect.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

My css says:

```
#navigationText a:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Here is a live link to the page where it is not happening: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/270523/help/initializr/index.html

Comment: Works for me... btw making link text the same style as normal text is bad for usability.

Comment: Strange. I'm seeing the same issue in chrome. When I change the font-family on those links to ``helvetica`` instead of ``Trend`` the hover appears.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer True, I'll consider playing with the styles to make them different enough.

Comment: @NickTomlin Oh, so it must be an issue with the custom font then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that even though the underline is not appearing, the bottom-border is and on hover.

So if I change the on hover css to:

```
#navigationText a:hover{
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

This is not the same, but it is a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font-family to a more generic/default typeface. When I toggle font-family:'Trend'; on line 95 of main.css via Chrome Dev Tools, the underline shows up on hover.

I'm not sure WHY it's happening, but I think that'll fix the issue.